# Fastest way to query column names from a table

Tags: sql-server, information-schema

I am looking for the fastest way to query the a list of columns from a given table in a database. I realize the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns` view exists in Microsoft SQL Server.

However, in PostgreSQL, I recall using the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns` to get a list of columns from a particular table and through experimentation if I remember correctly I found the following to be faster than using the information schema:

```
    SELECT *
    FROM pg_catalog.pg_tables
    WHERE schemaname != 'pg_catalog' 
    AND schemaname != 'information_schema';
```

From personal experience, querying might take 10ms on an objects table but 200ms from the information schema.

Does SQL Server have an equivalent faster way to get the list of columns from a given table like PostgreSQL does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [`sys.columns`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-columns-transact-sql) and [`sys.tables`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-tables-transact-sql) from the [Object Catalog Views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/object-catalog-views-transact-sql).

Performance differences aren't usually a concern for SQL Server, but the information schema views aren't well maintained and don't provide full coverage. See [The case against INFORMATION_SCHEMA views](https://sqlblog.org/2011/11/03/the-case-against-information_schema-views) by Aaron Bertrand.